# MFMailComposeViewController navigationBar override works in Simulator but not device

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

By default, my mail composer picks up the background image of it's presenting view controller. So I have logic to disable that background, which works like a champ in the simulator but not on a physical device (or at lease iPhone 4S. Both are using iOS 8.1

```
- (void)composeEmail
{
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{

        self.mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        self.mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        // Disable navbar styling in presenting VC
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


        NSString *emailTitle = @"Subject";
        NSString *messageBody = @"Body";

        //configure mail message

        [self.mailComposer setSubject:emailTitle];
        [self.mailComposer setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];


        // Present mail view controller on screen
        [self.callingController presentViewController:self.mailComposer animated:YES completion:^{
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

        }];
    }
} else {
    // alert here
}
}

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
switch (result)
{
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        NSLog(@"Mail saved");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent");
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

// Enable navbar styling in presenting VC
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

// Close the Mail Interface
[self.callingController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: What is not working, could you please elaborate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution is both simple and non-obvious. The command to modify the UINavigationBar has to come BEFORE the mail composer is allocated.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes in your code:

1. Use below line in compose email method

   ```
   [self.mailComposer.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   ```
2. Use below line in your didFinishWithResult method.

   ```
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Happy-Rose-Day.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   ```

I think last point might not required as you code is also working ([UINavigationBar appearance])